# What words go together with savvy? Business-savvy? Technology-savvy?

Tags: vocabulary, collocation

Are there rules to matching words with savvy?

Comment: An expert on mongooses could be called "riki-tiki-tavi-savvy."

Comment: Cloesly Related: "What words frequently collocate with *-wise*?" https://english.stackexchange.com/q/477901/14666

Comment: If I knew everything there was to know about the word *or* I could call myself *or*-savvy. The word can go together with any word in the right context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I collected all combinations of X+*savvy* from the [Corpus of Contemporary American English](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/old/) that occur at least twice. I then performed a [collexeme analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collostructional_analysis) to see which elements are most strongly associated with *savvy*. The first fifteen words returned as significant are shown below:

```
COLLEX CORP.FREQ OBS   EXP ASSOC   COLL.STR SIGNIF<br>
1          TECH      19470 215 0.0  attr 3615.96212  *****
2         MEDIA      82620  86 0.1  attr 1017.99493  *****
3      COMPUTER      65914  57 0.1  attr  650.71470  *****
4      INTERNET      46365  36 0.1  attr  401.94937  *****
5        TECHNO        442  16 0.0  attr  301.59169  *****
6           WEB      44812  19 0.0  attr  188.65202  *****
7      BUSINESS     183197  20 0.2  attr  144.62782  *****
8    TECHNOLOGY      85771  17 0.1  attr  142.97843  *****
9         CYBER       2711   9 0.0  attr  126.24371  *****
10       STREET     127545  15 0.1  attr  110.56134  *****
11 SOCIAL-MEDIA        298   5 0.0  attr   86.36998  *****
12       MARKET     116006  12 0.1  attr   85.34196  *****
13        STYLE      43980   9 0.0  attr   76.15033  *****
14          NET      22389   7 0.0  attr   65.11429  *****
15           PR       2926   5 0.0  attr   63.45697  *****
```

What we can see is that the first 6 words, *tech*, *media*, *computer*, *internet*, *techno*, *web*, as well as words 8 *technology*, 9 *cyber*, 11 *social-media*, and 14, *net* designate terms that have to do with **modern, predominantly computer-mediated technologies**. Hence, English seems to use *savvy* mainly in this context.

> (1) Typical, natural examples of X-*savvy* (computers):
> *internet-savvy*
> *social-media-savvy*
> *computer-savvy*

Other frequent collocates of *savvy* are words 7 *business*, 12 *market*, or 15 *PR*. Further words that appear later on the list are *fashion*, *money*, *food*, *wine*, *pop*, *design*, *investment* or *marketing*. Thus, another area of discourse that seems to create words with *savvy* naturally may be **modern, often lifestyle-defining service-sector industries**.

> (2) Typical, natural examples of X-*savvy* (business):
> *business-savvy*
> *market-savvy*
> *design-savvy*

If we pick a noun that denotes ancient technology or a domain of knowledge that is remote from a computer or modern business, we will likely create an odd, jocular, or otherwise unnatural compound.

> (3) Atypical, unnatural examples of X-*savvy*:
> *agriculture-savvy*
> *steam-engine-savvy*
> *horseback-riding-savvy*

Answer (score 2):

*Savvy* basically means "knowledge(able)" and can be a verb, an adjective, or a noun. See the various definitions with great examples on [Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/savvy). Here are a few simpler examples for a quick look:

- **Verb**: I savvy your question.
- **Noun**: The receptionist was very business-savvy. (Your question is about the noun)
- **Adj**: She is very savvy in the study of cat behavior.

It's a pretty flexible word. I had a gym teacher in middle school who always said "Savvy?" (long before Jack Sparrow did).

Comment: +1 Adds a lot to the discussion. Could do with some references from reliable sources, too. (See FAQ about answering.) Good Luck.

Comment: Thanks Kris! I updated to make it look a little prettier, and included a link to my source.

Answer (score 1):

Any noun which, in combination with savvy, is used to suggest that one is acquainted with or  experienced in a specific field:

***[Savvy](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/savvy):***

> (in combination) Well informed about or experienced in a particular domain.
>
> - ‘most of us are pretty web-savvy’
> - ‘these fashion-savvy consumers are not afraid of taking risks with little-known designers’

(ODO)